# Why is STR Available Inconsistently?

Tags: t-sql, function, ssis, dataflowtask

When I create a OLE DB source, I can use the following expression:

```
STR(1234.545, 8, 2)
```

But when I use a Derived-Column flow task, that expression is illegal.  The design-time error states:

> The function "SET" was not recognized.  Either the function name is
>   incorrect or does not exist.

I'd like to know why the function is not available to the Derived-Column task.  And in general, I'd like to know the rule governing which functions are in fact available, or perhaps a list of the functions that **are** available to the Derived-Column task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer what functions available in a [Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx), look at [Integration Services Expression Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141232.aspx). In particular, you are probably interested in [String Functions and Other Functions (SSIS Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141671.aspx)

Why SET works in OLE DB and not in derived column is rather straight forward, they're different technologies. The set statement runs against a database and is a declarative style language (SQL) while the derived column expression is an imperative style language (vb/c#/etc).

BTW, I have no idea what the reference SET statement would do or what OLE DB provider that would work for. Perhaps it was just an example.